# Can I issue a "heroku restart" command from within the app running at Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

My (Sinatra) app intermittently goes into a bad state that I have only been able to fix by restarting the Heroku dyno.  Of course I would like to fix the fundamental problem, but meanwhile, I'd like user not to be so inconvenienced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works.  It was NOT working on the Heroku "aspen" stack, but it is on the bamboo 1.9.2 stack.

```
require 'heroku'
~
~
heroku = Heroku::Client.new("YOUR EMAIL", "YOUR PASSWORD")
heroku.ps_restart("hacknews")
```

Answer (score 0):

How "bad" is the state? If the application is still running, you could probably use the `system` command in Ruby to issue the command.

But this seems like a bad idea. What you might want to do instead (until you fix the fundamental problem!) is have something external to the app monitoring it. Perhaps you can set up an instance of Nagios, God, or something...